# Change view visibility from another thread in another class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a view, let's call it, promptView that I need to open once a HTTP GET request is made. I have all my API code in another class and in order to make a GET request you must run it in another thread/async task/coroutine. For this case I decided to use a coroutine as it was simple and got the job done. Once the request is made and a <200> response is received it should open promptView that is in my main activity. I get the error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

My code to open promptView is:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
     mClass.promptView.isVisible = true
}
```

I am positive that `mClass.promptView.isVisible = true` is the problem as when I remove that and put for example a Log.d() in there it works well. I was wondering what I did wrong or what I can do to change a views visibility from another thread in another class. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do any UI related task from another thread and that is by design. If you still want to do any UI related modification you can use `runOnUiThread`

e.g.

```
this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
})
```

But I would recommend using MVVM pattern. There are a lot of examples available in Google codelabs or YouTube. More on app architecture : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Comment: Sounds good but can you even do ```this@MainActivity```. It just wants me to define MainActivity.

Comment: If you have context passed you can cast it to MainActivity but please try to use MVVM which is a recommended approach.

Comment: Ok sure! Ill try using mvvm